# How to create a fully dynamic table-builder component in Vue based on CSS Grid?

Tags: css, vue.js, html-table, css-grid, grid-layout

I need to create a table builder in Vue, based on css grid.
The problem I face is that columns count is not fixed, it depends on object keys, and in most cases columns width is not equal, so width of 1fr is not suitable for this case I guess.
The data I need to render in this table may be a vue component, or link, or string etc.
Would appreciate any help)

Comment: Do you have a list of all possible columns ? You could maybe use flexbox or CSS grid a requirement ?

Comment: you need to add in more details, I used to want to add in vue components for each cell, but I decided to use HTML5 custom elements. you can add a render function to render the cell according to what you need or use a slot (both vue and html5 custom elements have it)

What you are probably requiring is extremely non-trivial. You can look at this cookbook and the crud tables being build

https://github.com/ais-one/vue-crud-x (develop branch)

Comment: I have been working on it for 3 years already moving from vue2+vuetify to vue3+vaadin(html5 custom element) to vue3+own diy (bwc-table.js)

I am in the process of adding in an autocomplete component which can be used by the table (and any others that require it) that can be styled using bulma, bootstrap or muicss (basically css libraries at most accepting vanilla javascript)